# How to run South migrations for two (or multiple) Django test databases?

Tags: django, testing, migration, django-south, database-migration

In my apps settings.py file (then made available in `django.conf.settings`) I have specified:

```
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.parse(os.environ['DATABASE']),
             'secondary': dj_database_url.parse(os.environ['SECONDARY_DATABASE'])}

SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = True
```

But running my tests using `./manage.py test app_name` runs the migrations for the default database and creates some of the tables for the secondary database before failing with:

```
Creating test database for alias 'secondary' ('test_secondary')...
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
...
Creating table django_admin_log
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Migrating...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 18, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 49, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/simple.py", line 381, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/simple.py", line 317, in setup_databases
    self.verbosity, autoclobber=not self.interactive)
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/hacks/django_1_0.py", line 100, in wrapper
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 271, in create_test_db
    load_initial_data=False)
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 149, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 99, in handle_noargs
    management.call_command('migrate', **options)
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 149, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 108, in handle
    ignore_ghosts = ignore_ghosts,
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/__init__.py", line 171, in migrate_app
    south.db.db = south.db.dbs[database]
KeyError: 'secondary'
```